# Create arraylist of class and interface

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

I'm attempting to create an `ArrayList` (so java, obviously) with type `TileEntity` (yes this is a minecraft mod). But I also need the objects added to the `ArrayList` to implement a certain interface.

The first option that came to mind was creating an abstract subclass of `TileEntity` that implemented interface, and using that as the `ArrayList` type. But given the fact that people normally create their own subclasses of `TileEntity` and use those as the class they normally subclass, and I want people to be able to hook into my mod, I can't expect them to subclass anything besides `TileEntity`.

My current solution is to check `if(object instanceof MyInterface)` before adding, but that seems ugly. Surely there's a way to set the type of an `ArrayList` to require that an object be both a subclass of `TileEntity` and an implementor of `MyInterface`.

Comment: which version of java are you using?

Comment: Similar question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592832/java-generics-parameter-bounding-to-any-of-a-range-of-types

Comment: I'm using java 6. 7 doesn't work for minecraft development on mac os. Some weird bug with the way lwjgl binds to the awt canvas.

Answer (score 6):

You can make generic the method or class where the `ArrayList` is used. For example, a generic method:

```
public <T extends TileEntity & MyInterface> void doStuffWith(T obj) {
    List<T> yourList = new ArrayList<T>();
    yourList.add(obj);
    ...//more processing
}
```

And a generic class:

```
public class ArrayListProcessor<T extends TileEntity & MyInterface> {
   List<T> theList;

   public void processList(T obj) {
      theList.add(obj);
      ...
   }

   public void someOtherMethod() {
      T listElem = theList.get(0);
      listElem.callMethodFromTileEntity();//no need to cast
      listElen.callMethodFromMyInterface();//no need to cast
   }
}

...//somewherein your code
//SomeObj extends TileEntity and implements MyInterface 
ArrayListProcessor<SomeObj> proc = new ArrayListProcessor<SomeObj>();
```

Comment: +1. Multiple bounds are discussed in this Java tutorial http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. I was unaware generics had this ability.

Comment: Hm... Actually, I'm having a problem now. The arraylist is actually an instance variable, and I can't have the class use a generic type, because then only the T my class was initialized with can be added. Although, having it this way on the method used to add to the arraylist works. Just means I have to cast to my interface all over the place in the class.

Comment: I don't understand. Why casting? The object should already implement `MyInterface`. Post some sample code from the class: the method and where you need to cast.

Comment: Well it's pretty simple. I can't give a generic type to the whole of the class because then I'm bound to one class for T. So therefore I can only create an ArrayList of an existing type. So I have to choose between TileEntity and MyInterface. So everywhere in the class except the method that adds the object to the list has to cast to MyInterface when I want to use the interface methods.

Sorry I can't post code. I'm away from the dev environment right now.

Comment: In my opinion this need for casting to both `TileEntity` and `MyInterface` is one more reason to make the class generic in T. I'll update the answer shortly.

Comment: agreed but that simply isn't an option. I can't declare 'myobj = new MyClass<someclass>();' because I need to be able to add instances of any subclass of TileEntity & MyInterface, not just instances of someclass.

Comment: I understand now. Maybe you can refactor such that the `ArrayList` is removed from the class and here you just process an `ArrayList` elem. Just thinking...

Answer (score 0):

You could add whatever methods of `TileEntity` you need to your interface, and just make the `ArrayList` of your interface. There is probably some fancy way of using generics to solve the problem in a better way, but I'm unsure how.

**EDIT:** dcernahoschi's solution is much better.