# Why do generic types have the same signature?

Tags: java, generics

I have the following generic class:

```
class Or<A,B>
{
  Or (A a) {}
  Or (B b) {}
}
```

Why do I get the following error when I try to compile it:

```
Or(A) is already defined in Or
    Or (B b)
    ^
```

It seems to me that the two constructors share the same signature although they have different generic type arguments. Why? And how to work around this problem?

**Update**

I understood the problem now. The compiler needs a way to distinguish the two types. Adding such a constrain would be ok for my use case. So I would like to add another question:

How to specify that the two types A and B may be anything but different?

Comment: Legacy [*type erasure*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java#Problems_with_type_erasure).

Comment: @johnchen902, can you add this comment as answer? It would be great

Comment: @PrasadKharkar Because this question obviously a duplicate. I don't want to be the first answerer before I see someone 10k or more answer.

Comment: You can't have a union of types, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592832/java-generics-parameter-bounding-to-any-of-a-range-of-types

Comment: Keep in mind that Java generics are a compiler fiction.  There is essentially nothing in the compiled code that "remembers" they're generic.

Comment: @DavidRoussel As the answer to the linked question states you can have a union by using a common interface. However, what the OP wants is a disjunction. And this is indeed not possible to be defined explicitly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> It seems to me that the two constructors share the same signature although they have different generic type arguments.

They do. The signature is

```
Or(Object o);
```

> Why?

Because of [*type erasure*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) implementation of generics in Java: references to generic types are converted to `System.Object` in all contexts where they are used; the generic type is known only to the compiler.

> And how to work around this problem?

Unfortunately, you cannot easily work around this problem in a constructor. You can replace the overloaded constructors with factory methods, and give different names, say `OrWithA` and `OrWithB`:

```
// Hide the constructor
private Or(...) {
    ...
}
// Publish factory methods
public static <X> Or OrWithA(X a) {
    return new Or(...);
}
public static <X> Or OrWithB(X a) {
    return new Or(...);
}
```

Comment: Does not work, because `non-static class A cannot be referenced from a static context`.

Comment: @ceving Thanks, I forgot about some limitations of Java generics after several years of working with C#. You can make your factory methods generic on some other type (see the edit), although it is certainly not as elegant as if you could use `A` and `B`.

Answer (score 2):

They just do. That's the nature of generics; they provide syntatic sugar used only at compile time. There is no way round it.

(Acknowledge question comments) This is called type erasure: see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_erasure

Answer (score 2):

This is because A or B can be anything, they can be same also as generics is just for compile time. At runtime, they are lost due to type erasure

Comment: It's nothing to do with runtime types.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). The Eclipse compiler gives a more detailed error:
`Method Or(A) has the same erasure Or(Object) as another method in type Or`

If you apply restrictions to the generics it compiles just fine:

```
class Or<A extends String, B extends Integer>
{
    Or(A a) {}

    Or(B b) {}
}
```

Comment: I would need the constrain: A extends anything but the class of B. The types should be distinct. How to specify this?

Comment: @ceving It's not possible to specify something as general as "anything except B". You need two concrete classes or interfaces that are distinct.

Answer (score 1):

To say it differently: You have 2 types, A and B, and nothing is known about both of them. So one completely unknown type is as good as another one. How should the constructor calls be dispatched?

Answer (score 0):

This is not legal, since generics are discarded at runtime (this is type erasure). Both of your methods would have a prototype of `Or(Object)`.

The only solution would be to have a `OrA()` and `OrB()` method -- or review your class entirely.

Answer (score 0):

That's because of a [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html): generics are replaced with Object type on compilation, so your methods do have the same signature. As a workaound you may choose to narrow the types of A and B:

```
public class Test<A extends String, B extends Number> {

public Test(A arg){

}

public Test(B arg){

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These constructors will be seen as having the same signatures since their types cannot be identified at runtime.

Try specifying a bounds on at least one of the type parameters if possible.

```
class Or<A extends Number,B>
{
  Or (A a) {}
  Or (B b) {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Consider this, which constructor to call?

   ```
   Or<Integer,Integer> o = new Or<>(5);
   ```
2. Your problem really comes from **Type erasure**, it make your code look like this after compilation:

   ```
   class Or
   {
       Or (Object a) {}
       Or (Object b) {}
   }
   ```

Comment: How to specify that the types may be anything but distinct? That would be fine for my use case and should be sufficient for the compiler.

Comment: @ceving No, you cannot, I'm afraid. However maybe you can use [factory method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/929273/2040040)