# Generics map key should allow two classes only and value one class

Tags: java, generics

Using generics I want to make my method parameterize to accept map of key (A or B) and value as Model which later it transforms into map of `Map<UUID, Model>`

The problem is that I get an error on `entry.getKey().getId()` b/c. I have not defined what is ? a key. Can someone help?

```
public void method(Map<?, Model> map) {
  Map<UUID, Model> transformation =
      map.entrySet().stream()
          .collect(
              Collectors.toMap(entry -> entry.getKey().getId(), entry -> entry.getValue()));
}

class S {
  protected UUID getId() {
    // return UUID
  }
}

class A extends S {}

class B extends S {}

class Model {
  // bla bla
}
```

Comment: Related: [Java generics parameter bounding to any of a range of types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6592832/1371329)

Comment: You can solve this by implementing a custom type: `Either<A, B>` (or taking one from some library). It will impact your type signature to a degree, but in the end will actually give you the type safety benefits. On the other hand, I see no practical use in implementing a dictionary where the key can be one of two completely unrelated things, I'd rather have two separate maps for that.

Comment: ... Reading a little more into this (I must be blind, for sure!), you do have a common type `S`. Then go for what The answers suggested, and use `? extends S`.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov even if there were no common type, a less invasive solution would be to provide a functional parameter to the method to extract the UUID: `method(mapOfA, A::getId)`.

Comment: @AndyTurner, true, he can just "explain" to the transformation method how to obtain a `UUID` from any key type by adding a function parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `A` and `B` implement a common interface offering the `getId()` method, bound the wildcard with that:

```
public void method(Map<? extends S, Model> map) {
```

Comment: Or just add the interface if not exists

Comment: @StoyanRadnev it does.

Answer (score 0):

Because `A` and `B` both extend `S`, the generic key to your `map` can simply be `S`:

```
public void method(Map<? extends S, Model> map) {
```

There's not much that you can currently do to limit other children of `S` from being the key in your map (until Java gets sealed classes), besides creating some interface that both `A` and `B` implement, and then using that interface as the generic key of `map`.

Comment: Note that this won't accept a `Map<A, Model>` as a parameter.

Comment: He can do `Either<A, B>` as a custom type to emulate sealed sets, but that would require some custom code in map implementation.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov can you help with custom implementation ?

Comment: @d-man, do you have to make a custom implementation though? I'd go for what is in the answer personally, unless you really do need sealed types emulated. But then you couldn't add a third type in there without severely rewriting the code.